# trying to print a method from arraylist

Tags: java

I am trying to print title from my member class using array in my library class
 public class Book gives me this error :
http://screencast.com/t/tqpJp2BF8sH

```
       {
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int x;
    private Integer bookid;
    private String author;
    private String title;
    private String ficornonfic;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Book
     */
    public Book(Integer bookID, String Author, String Title, String FictionORnonfiction  )
    {
        bookid = bookID;
        author = Author;
        title = Title  ; 
        ficornonfic = FictionORnonfiction;
        x = 0;
    }


    public String PrintListOfBooks()
  {

        return title;

    }

    public String toString() {
     return "Title:" + title + " BookId: " + bookid  + " Author: " + author + ".";
   }
   public int getTitle() {
     return this.title;
}
}
                ---------------------------------------------------------
```

this is my library class

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;



    public class Library
    {


        private ArrayList<Member>listOfMembers;
        public Library()
        {
            listOfMembers = new ArrayList<Member>();
             listOfBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
        }
        public void storeMember(Member Member)
        {
            listOfMembers.add(Member);
        }
        public int numberOfMembers()
        {
            return listOfMembers.size();
        }

        public void listMembers()
       {
       for (int item=0; item<listOfMembers.size(); item++ ) {
         Member m = listOfMembers.get (item);
        System.out.println(m.GetWholeName());
            }
        } 

    public Member findMember(int id) {

         for(Member member : listOfMembers) {
             if (member.getId() == id) {
                  return member;
             }
         }

         return null;
    }

    private ArrayList<Book>listOfBooks;

        public void storeBook(Book Book)
        {
            listOfBooks.add(Book);
        }
        public int numberOfBooks()
        {
            return listOfBooks.size();
        }

        public void listBooks()
       {
       for (int item=0; item<listOfBooks.size(); item++ ) {
         Book b = listOfBooks.get (item);
        System.out.println(b.PrintListOfBooks());
            }
        }

        public Book findBook(string title) {

         for(Book book : listOfBooks) {
             if (book.getId() == id) {
                  return book;
             }
         }

         return null;
    }


    }
```

I am trying to print title from my member class using array in my library class
 public class Book gives me this error :
http://screencast.com/t/tqpJp2BF8sH

Comment: Please include the error message in the post itself, instead of as a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as others have noted your `title` is a `String` not an `int`. So change the return type of `getTitle()` (or remove it altogether). Because it appears like you've correctly overridden `toString()` in `Book` to get all the information, and you could iterate the contents of your `List` with a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html). Something like,

```
for (Book b : listOfBooks) {
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfBooks.size(); i++) {
    Book b = listOfBooks.get(i);
    System.out.println(b.toString());
}
```

Finally in Java, by convention, method names start with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 2):

The `title` is a `String`, not an `int`. You can change the method signature to match the field type:

```
public String getTitle() {
    return this.title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially telling the program to return an Integer when the value you wish to return is a String.

If you change int to String, the error will go away.

```
public String getTitle() {
return this.title;
```

}